# Using useEffect with Axios API call without constant rerendering (with Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm fetching data from an API within a file which is the context provider of my React application. However, when I push some data to the API, from a component consuming the context, the data isn't updated in real time, and I have to refresh the page to see it update. How do I make sure it keeps checking the API for new data?

I have added the items state to the dependency array in the useEffect function but this results in the API being constantly called, as opposed to only when the data changes.

`ItemsContext.tsx`

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState();


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>
      {
        try {
          const res = await axios.get(config().URI);
          setItems(res.data.items);
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you want useEffect to work according to a change on the frontend, you can add it to the array. But if you want a server-side trigger, you need to use websocket.

Comment: add what to the array?

Comment: which value do you want to listen from props or state ?

Comment: the items value. but when I add the items value to the dependency array, it constantly rerenders and thus keeps calling the API

Comment: Of course, because it will change constantly. Is the value of items being changed elsewhere?

Comment: Just within one component. I push the new value to the API from said component but the value immediately reverts back to the previous API response and continues calling the api.